# EF/WCF: Reducing data transfer

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework, serialization

Hopefully, this is not too open-ended. I'm working on a `.NET 4, WPF, WCF, EF (STE's), SQL 2012` application.

We're getting hammered by our customers because our application times out and hangs on slower networks when there's not much bandwidth available.

Our application has a few 'realtime' dashboard-like displays as well as a few grid-based data editor screens.

Using Fiddler, I took a closer look at the different feature areas within the product - specifically focusing on the amount of data that's being transferred. In short, there's way too much data being transferred - some of our WCF calls retrieve more than 100 MB of data in a single call.

I believe the issues we’re seeing can be characterized by the fact that there’s simply not enough care taken when retrieving data via WCF and EF, but maybe I’m over analyzing things:

- I'm a huge fan of re-usability, but why return a completely hydrated
  EF STE entity when all you need is an id and a name for a picklist?
  Sometimes, we need just a simple read-only display of the data. Why
  serialize the ChangeTracker information including the OriginalValues
  collection, etc.? Perhaps, it’s worth splitting out the entities into
  editable and “readonly versions” or picklist appropriate versions?
- Right now, we’re using BasicHttpBinding/XML Serialization, but the
  payload seems bloated. For example, the xml contains namespaces and a
  bunch of other noise. Enabling IIS 7 compression has helped
  drastically, but is there more we can do? Would JSON format be a
  better bet for transferring data? Changing XML to JSON seems like it
  major change though.
- Are there any other techniques that could be used to mitigate the
  payload size – perhaps we can stick with XML Serialization, but we
  simply need to request less data. Maybe using techniques like paging
  or “infinity scrolling,” deferred background loading, etc. would be a
  good bet.

Has anyone else been faced with an unacceptably large payload size? What did you do to resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you ask EF to return a collection of objects then it will do exactly that even if you only need the ID.

Comment: True. But we don't necessarily need to serialize the complete object to give to the client. In these cases, translating to a simple, read-only DTO with just the Id and Name would lighten up the payload.

Comment: Exactly.  If you don't need the entire object then don't ask for entire object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've covered the big ones.

Use DTOs instead of full entities whenever possible (simple data types with only the data you need). You'll just need a simple translation class - you can even use code-generation tools or something like AutoMapper to help you here.

Use NetTcpBinding instead of BasicHttpBinding - that'll reduce the message size significantly, but you'll lose the HTTP/Fiddler debugging, and it will require some IIS configuration.

Or if you want to stick with HTTP and use JSON instead of XML, you won't be able to do it easily with WCF BasicHttpBinding, since that's SOAP, but you can shift gears and try WebAPI instead. That would be a significant change to both the client and server though.

Those should cut your size down by quite a bit. From there, keep exploring bringing in the data in chunks, or using lots of individual queries instead of one big one. Even if those don't reduce overall bandwidth, they will provide a better user experience.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and the insight.